# Redirect to login page on specific store

Tags: magento2, plugin

I would like to redirect the customer from any page of the store to the login page if he isn't already logged in. I guess I need to make a plugin or an observer on some dispatch or forward method, but I can't guess which one is the one to check any new called url. Does any of you already did that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with the use of events. Please add below events and observer code in your custom module.

> step 1: Please create file events.xml under path
> PackageName/Module/etc/frontend/

Write below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="redirectcustomer_success" instance="PackageName\Module\Observer\RedirectCustomer" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Please create file RedirectCustomer.php under path
> PackageName/Module/Observer/

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as HttpResponse;

class RedirectCustomer implements ObserverInterface
{
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    protected $responseFactory;

    protected $_customerSession;

    protected $_customerUrl;

    protected $_urlInterface;

    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {   
        $redirectUrl = $this->getCustomerLoginUrl(); 
        $currentUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl(); 
        $fullActionName = $this->request->getFullActionName();

        if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn() && $currentUrl != $redirectUrl &&  $fullActionName != 'customer_account_forgotpassword' && $fullActionName != 'customer_account_createpassword' && $fullActionName != 'customer_section_load') {
            $resultRedirect = $this->responseFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setRedirect($redirectUrl)->sendResponse('200');
            exit();
        }   
    }

    public function getCustomerLoginUrl() 
    {   
        return $this->_customerUrl->getLoginUrl();
    }
}
```

In above code, we are allowing forgot password and rest password. If you don't want then you can remove it from condition.

Please check and let us know

Cheers!

Comment: Was trying to do that with a Plugin of getUrl and I was struggling. Your way is the good one thanks ;)